# Grouping multiple dates in Spark SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having trouble grouping the dates in my code.

This is my code so far:

```
df_tipReview = spark.sql("""
SELECT R.user_id, R.date, COUNT(R.review_id), T.date
FROM reviews AS R INNER JOIN tips AS T
ON R.user_id = T.user_id
GROUP BY R.date, T.date, R.user_id
""")
df_tipReview.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EQMe.png

As you can see, the same `user_id` has the same date listed, how would I aggregate that in Spark SQL so that it would essentially look like:

`|-55DgUo52I3zW9RxkZ-EAQ|2015-11-11| 3`

Instead of having that it on multiple lines.

Thanks.

So when I tried to use the distinct function as below:

```
df_tipReview = spark.sql("""
SELECT DISTINCT R.user_id, R.date, COUNT(R.review_id), T.date
FROM reviews AS R INNER JOIN tips AS T
ON R.user_id = T.user_id
GROUP BY R.user_id, R.date, T.date
""")
df_tipReview.filter("R.user_id='-55DgUo52I3zW9RxkZ-EAQ'").show(truncate=False)
```

This is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ercES.png

Comment: Your output only has 3 columns.  What happened to `T.date` ?  Please include sample data.

Comment: T.Date is different for each row thats why output is like this. remove T.date

Comment: T.date is a different column that has nothing to do with R.date. I didn't include it in the picture because it would affect it or would it?

Comment: T.date is essentially Tip date and R.date is review date. They are two suppose to be two different dates

Comment: That description doesn't help much.  Show sample input and the expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated the original post with new pics

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If you clearly look at the pictures you see duplicate. It's not hard to envision an output

Comment: No...we need to see the original table data in order to formulate a correct query.  It is very hard to back out a query by looking at _incorrect_ output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OK. To make it clear I am looking for the correct function to use in SQL to aggregate the date. I'm not sure how a view of the original table will help at all. It'll be a screenshot, you can't navigate through it.

Answer (score 0):

Have You Tried Select Distinct???

```
    df_tipReview = spark.sql("""
    SELECT Distinct R.user_id, R.date, COUNT(R.review_id), T.date
    FROM reviews AS R INNER JOIN tips AS T
    ON R.user_id = T.user_id
    GROUP BY R.date, T.date, R.user_id
    """)
    df_tipReview.show(truncate=False)
```

Please share some data so it's easier to help you

Comment: I have but I've only tried distinct around a column. Let me try to see what the output is if I distinct the entire table

Comment: I just tried what you did, but there's still duplicates. I will add on the picture to the original post so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Remove T.date from selection list as well from group by
from your expected result it seems you don't need T.date in selectionlist

```
df_tipReview = spark.sql("""
SELECT R.user_id, R.date, COUNT(R.review_id) as cnt
FROM reviews AS R INNER JOIN tips AS T
ON R.user_id = T.user_id
GROUP BY R.date, R.user_id
""")
```